# How to create Titanium View Proxy Method and access it from titanium project?

Tags: ios, module, proxy, titanium, appcelerator

I am learning titanium iOS module development these days. I have problem with creating public methods in View Proxy and access it from titanium module.

I have a method in View class . I need to access the method while user interact with it

Example :

```
gaugeview.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) {

    var thetaValue = gauge.Theta; // Theta is method
    Ti.API.info('theta value touchmove'+thetaValue);

});
```

I should use view proxy method here but i don't how to implement it. Please help me to learn this stuff.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To work with the view proxy you should be creating iOS module development.
All your public function are defined there.
here is the links which will help you to learn module development.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide

and

here is a tutorial to create a simple iOS module

http://iosmuncher.blogspot.in/2012/01/extending-titanium-project-with-ios.html